# ostream_iterator for a vector<int> does not compile. Why?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, ostream

Please see the following minimum reproducable example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// Define inserter operator for std::vector<int>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::vector<int>& v) {
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, " "));
    return os;
}
// Define inserter operator for std::vector<std::vector<int>>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vv) {
    
    // ******* Error in this line *****
    std::copy(vv.begin(), vv.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::vector<int>>(os,"\n"));

    // OK. The following works and will call the operator above
    for (const std::vector<int>& v : vv) os << v << '\n';
    return os;
}
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vvi{ {1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8,9 } };
    std::cout << vvi;
    return 0;
}
```

The `std::ostream_iterator<std::vector<int>>` will not compile, compiler says:

> binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Although an inserter operator for `std::vector<int>` is available.

if I instead use:

```cpp
for (const std::vector<int>& v : vv) os << v << '\n';
```

The insert operator for `std::vector<int>` will be called. But not in the case of the `std::ostream_iterator`.

CppReference does not help me.

Why does this not compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you're missing an

```
#include <iterator>
```

You indicate that you're already familiar with cppreference.com, so you should take note that `std::ostream_iterator` is noted as requiring this header file.

But the real reason for the compilation failure is that the overloaded operator is invoked by `std::copy` which, naturally, is in the `std` namespace. Since the code that invokes the `<<` operator is in the `std` namespace, overload resolution searches the `std` namespace for the defined overloads of `<<`, and finds a whole bunch of them, for various native types. All of those overload resolutions fail. None of them are for `std::vector<int>`. The global namespace is ***not*** searched, to find your custom `<<` overload, since at least one `<<` overload is found in the `std` namespace. Game over.

If there were no defined `<<` overloads in the `std` namespace, then overload resolution will eventually find your custom overload. Alas, that is not the case.

One way to make the compilation error go away is to put your overload into the `std` namespace:

```
namespace std {
    // Define inserter operator for std::vector<int>
    std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::vector<int>& v) {
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, " "));
        return os;
    }
}
```

However, [this is pedantic undefined behavior](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.constraints#namespace.std-1). In any case, this is the reason for the compilation error: the existing overloads for `<<` are searched in the `std` namespace first, because they are invoked from within `std::copy`, and existing overload resolutions are found first, and so other potential overloads in other namespaces are not considered.

Comment: Good and understandable explanation. Im still dissatisfied that there is oviously no compliant solution for my problem. So, I will wrap the inserters in a class or create a proxy for the extractors. Anyway, +1+accept

Comment: Don’t you mean the problem is because `operator<<` is invoked by **`std::ostream_iterator`**, not by `std::copy()` itself?  `std::copy()` has no concept of `operator<<`, since it is just copying values from one iterator to another.  It is `std::ostream_iterator` that invokes `operator<<`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You are right. Compiler error can be tracked down to the assignment operator of the class ````ostream_iterator````. It happens in the line ````*_Myostr << _Val;````